# where's the code for Calculator showcase?

Tags: calculator, qooxdoo

Where can I see the code for the calculator? I mean the one with fancy background? By the way, it looks very nice!!

In general, I could not find enough material for custom-made decoration, by searching the documents. Please let me know where I can learn deeper about rendering and widget decoration.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the source code of the calculator page in the qooxdoo SDK under

`qooxdoo/application/showcase/source/class/showcase/page/theme/calc/`

There is also a standalone version of the calculator on [github](http://github.com/fjakobs/Calculator). You can find more information about theming in the qooxdoo manual:

- [Theming](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.0/ui_theming)
- [Appearance](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.0/ui_appearance)
- [Custom Themes](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.0/ui_custom_themes)
- [Decorators](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.0/ui_decorators)